# Using Word Boundary in Regex that exceeds Word Length for Negative Lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, word-boundary

Sorry if that title doesn't fully explain my issue. Yesterday someone kindly pointed out how to get from here:

```
(?<STREET>(?!The|Long)\w+ Drive)
```

which was giving me results like

- STREET: he Drive

by using word boundaries:

?(?!The|Long)\b\w+ Drive)

which worked like a charm (STREET returned no match for 'The Street')  However I am now faced with the issue that though I am looking for 1 word prefixes to 'Drive' and I have 1 word exclusions, I cannot figure out how to make the exclusions longer.  For instance

- Mile Drive

is fine but

- a Mile Drive
- quick Mile Drive

is not. This is really just an example, not trying to solve this one specific instance; how to exclude a term vs a word from a single word portion of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match one or more words just use grouping and plus:

```
(?<STREET>(?!The|Long)(\b\w+ )+Drive)
```

as plus `+` matches one or more. Alternatively if you have a certain number of words you want to match try using `{}` for instance to match between 1 and 4 words use:

```
(?<STREET>(?!The|Long)(\b\w+ ){1,4}Drive)
```

Comment: Hi in fact I am looking to match SingleWord Drive while excluding certain SingleWords (e.g. Long). However in some cases I do want Long Drive just not when it is 'a long drive'. So I am trying to capture a two word phrase, excluding certain first words altogether and other first words only if they are preceded by other words.

Comment: Ok, your question still seems somewhat unclear. If you could give a more concrete example of what you want to do i might be able to help. :)